# Inserting custom css class into a xslt variable

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a xsl variable that has value

`<p> <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Illustrating tips</a> </p>`

How can I insert a css class to make the value of the variable, which will look like below. I also want to remove the paragraph tags.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="titleClass">Illustrating tips</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

```
<xsl:variable name="frag">
  <p> <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Illustrating tips</a> </p>
</xsl:variable>
```

then use a `mode` to transform it, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="p" mode="m1">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[@href]" mode="m1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">titleClass</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="m1"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:variable name="transformed-frag">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$frag/node()" mode="m1"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

or directly where you want to output the result

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$frag/node()" mode="m1"/>
```

If the `a` element can contain more than plain text, you will need to add templates for them copying them in the mode, like a general identity transformation template or like an identity transformation template in that mode e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="m1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```