# How to get first element value depending on attribute condition value when they are multiple elements in document xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a documents looks like below

```
<list>
    <document>
        <content type="text" name="title" action="cluster" weight="3" output-action="bold" vse-streams="2" u="113">
Sample action steps/best practices</content>
        <content type="html" name="title" output-action="bold" weight="3" vse-streams="2" u="146">
Survey Dimension: Excellence in All We Do</content>
<content name="fileextension" action="none" weight="1" type="text" output-action="bold" vse-streams="2" u="43">
pdf</content>
<content name="filetypelabel" action="none" weight="1" type="text" output-action="" vse-streams="2" u="45">
word</content>
    </document>
    <document>
        <content type="text" name="title" action="cluster" weight="3" output-action="bold" vse-streams="2" u="113">
Sample steps/best practices</content>
        <content type="html" name="title" output-action="bold" weight="3" vse-streams="2" u="146">
Survey : Excellence in All We Do</content>
<content name="fileextension" action="none" weight="1" type="text" output-action="bold" vse-streams="2" u="43">
excel</content>
<content name="filetypelabel" action="none" weight="1" type="text" output-action="" vse-streams="2" u="45">
ppt</content>
    </document>
</list>
```

when I transform it using xslt 2.0

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">
    <xsl:template match="list/document">
        <xsl:for-each select ="content">
            <xsl:variable name="title" select="." />
            <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
        </xsl:for-each >
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the out as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Sample action steps/best practices
Survey Dimension: Excellence in All We Do
pdf
word

Sample steps/best practices
Survey : Excellence in All We Do
excel
ppt
```

But my requirement is to consider the first element value when @name='title' in both documents.

So expected result should look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Sample action steps/best practices

Sample steps/best practices
```

Comment: Please take care of a previous question of yours, it has an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34285582/1987598) that you should [accept or otherwise react to](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34840940/1987598) also needs your attention: it is unclear right now, but you could improve it by showing samples of the actual XML input and output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are several unused namespaces in your XSLT stylesheet:

```
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
```

remove this clutter from the code. Then, for something as easy as just using the value of an element, there is no need to store it in an `xsl:variable` element, just use `xsl:value-of` directly:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

> But my requirement is to consider the first element value when @name='title' in both documents

Simply put those rules into a *predicate*:

```
content[@name = 'title' and position() = 1]
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="content[@name = 'title' and position() = 1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

```
[Empty line here]
Sample action steps/best practices
Sample steps/best practices
```

If whitespace control is important to you, you might prefer something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/list">
      <xsl:for-each select="document/content[@name = 'title' and position() = 1]">
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:transform>
```